# Why does my floodfill not fill image completly?

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, png, flood-fill

I have a feeling this has something to do with the pixel counting, however I cant seem to figure out how to extend the matching to cover the entire shape.

see Image example:

I have added a running example here:

[Working site](https://char.myprim.co.uk/tst/tst.html)

This is the flood fill function 1:

```
    function getPixel(imageData, x, y) {
      if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y >= imageData.height) {
        return [-1, -1, -1, -1];
      } else {
        const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
        return imageData.data.slice(offset, offset + 4);
      }
    }
```

Set pixel color

```
    function setPixel(imageData, x, y, color) {
      const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
      imageData.data[offset + 0] = color[0];
      imageData.data[offset + 1] = color[1];
      imageData.data[offset + 2] = color[2];
      imageData.data[offset + 3] = color[0];
    }
```

find color function:

```
   function colorsMatch(a, b) { 
         
      return a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1] && a[2] === b[2] && a[3] === b[3];
     
    }
```

Populate pixel array

```
    function floodFill(ctx, x, y, fillColor) {
    
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);          
      
      const targetColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);          
    
      if (!colorsMatch(targetColor, fillColor)) {
            
        const pixelsToCheck = [x, y];
        while (pixelsToCheck.length > 0) {
            const y = pixelsToCheck.pop();
            const x = pixelsToCheck.pop();

            const currentColor = getPixel(imageData, x, y);
            if (colorsMatch(currentColor, targetColor)) {
                setPixel(imageData, x, y, fillColor);                   
                pixelsToCheck.push(x + 1, y);
                pixelsToCheck.push(x - 1, y);
                pixelsToCheck.push(x, y + 1);
                pixelsToCheck.push(x, y - 1);
            }
        }           
        
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        
      }
    }
```

It works fine but leaves a few pixels on the side un filled,

Comment: Please post some more code.

Comment: please share more code details